# XMLHTTPRequest error while trying to add d3 to project

Tags: d3.js, webpack

I am trying to add d3.js to my webpack, angualrjs project using npm and keep getting the following error which looks to be a problem with webpack:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'child_process' in 
/Desktop/my-project/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib
```

I installed d3.js using npm and then when I try to add it to my app.js file(entry point for webpack)

```
 import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

I get the error. Its been driving me crazy and I cant get it fixed. Anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem while building my project that was using D3 (V 4.12.0) and another npm module "d3-context-menu". Further investigation reveled that somehow the "d3-context-menu" was making webpack to build d3 which was failing with same error mentioned by you.

I could solve this by upgrading D3 to latest version by command:
`npm install d3@latest --save`

This installed D3 latest version i.e. 5.7.0 and it solved the build errors.

You may try this option if it is feasible to upgrade D3 and see if this fix your problem.